# Predicted values for bootstrapping with bootMer?

Tags: r, lme4, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to run bootstrap simulations for a mixed model developed in `lmer`. The model looks like this:

```
model1<-lmer(Hg~A+B+C+D+(1|K),data=mydata)
```

I wrote the `bootMer` command like this:

```
bootfit1<-bootMer(model1,FUN=function(x)predict(x,re.form=NA),nsim=1000)
```

It works!  But when I plot `bootfit1` values with my actual and model predicted values, the `bootfit1` values are closer to 0 than the actual and predicted.  In my data `Hg` is technically normally distributed but is actually skewed towards `0`.

So here's my question: is there any way to control how much of each of the simulated data sets in the bootstrap are drawn from the actual data and how many are purely simulated?  I'm wondering if because my data is skewed the bootstrap simulations are not picking up many of the values that are well above 0.

[image]

Comment: `bootMer` uses *parametric* bootstrapping.  It would be worth trying https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmeresampler/index.html ...